# gradle no signature of a java method (hashmap.getOrDefault) applicable

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

This happened while I'm trying to build with Gradle. There seems to be no reason for this error to occur as Strings are Objects:

```
No signature of method: java.util.HashMap.getOrDefault() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [profile, development]
Possible solutions: getOrDefault(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)
```

Code:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = '1.8'

def DEFAULT_PROFILE = 'development'
def profile = project.getProperties().getOrDefault("profile", DEFAULT_PROFILE)
def config = new ConfigSlurper(profile).parse(file("profiles.gradle").toURL())
```

Note I'm using Intellij Idea rather than Eclipse as my IDE, for a project made in Eclipse. This is also my first time using Gradle, so might be some beginner's mistake.

Comment: The text of that error looks really strange to me. Almost as if method lookup ignores class inheritance in this case.

Comment: How did you declared your map variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea why this should happen, other than that the `Object` class the `String` class extends comes from a different classloader than the `Object` class the `HashMap` is using in the parameters. With stuff like that you can also produce messages like `could not cast java.lang.String to java.lang.String`, because the same class loaded from different classloaders are *not* the same class, but different ones regarding instanceof checks.

Maybe if you would provide a MCVE or the actual project as a whole one could make up what's going on.

Actually you could instead use a more Groovy style:

```
project.findProperty("profile") ?: DEFAULT_PROFILE
```

Comment: yeah, that makes sense! if they are loaded from two different places... I'll try and see what I can do.

Comment: This is the exact problem. I changed the Gradle jvm to be the same as the project, and it worked.